# I couldn't type in input text field

Tags: reactjs

```
    function Feature() {
        const initialState = {
            articles: [
                {
                    id: id.next(),
                    title: "Article 1",
                    summary: "Article 1 Summary",
                display: 'none'
            },
            {
                id: id.next(),
                title: "Article 2",
                summary: "Article 2 Summary",
            display: 'none'
        },
        {
            id: id.next(),
            title: "Article 3",
            summary: "Article 3 Summary",
        display: 'none'
        }
            ],
        title: "",
        summary: ""
        };
        const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
        const {articles, title, summary} = state;

******Code to be see******
        const onChangeTitle = e =>{
            setState({title: e.target.value});
            console.log(e)
        }
        const onChangeSummary = e =>{
            setState({summary: e.target.value})
        }
        **strong text**

        return (
            <section>
                <h1>Articles</h1>
```

rea
**strong text**
<input name="title" placeholder="Title"  value = {title} onChange={()=>onChangeTitle}>
<input name="summary" placeholder = "Summary" value={summary} onChange = {()=>onChangeSummary}>
**strong text**

Comment: Please describe the scenario and problem correctly

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but, from whatever I can understand:

You have passed `value-{title}` to the input. Change it to `value-{state.title}`